# Erlang, return second entry in tuple of variable lengths

Tags: erlang

So I have two tuples `{"A",3,"B",5}`, and `{"Hello",8}`. I want a function that returns the second entry in a tuple.

```
ret2(_,A) -> A.
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't catch the long tuples. How to pattern match only the first part?

Comment: Tuples are one block so you have match the whole tuple in one go.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `element(2, Tuple)`, like this:

```
2> element(2, {"A",3,"B",5}).
3
3> element(2, {"Hello",8}).
8
```

There is an example of this (and some other tuple manipulation functions) in [the Tuples section of the Data Types chapter of the Erlang Reference Manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id64600).